# Adjust ckeditor configuration in Sulu 2.2.1

Tags: ckeditor5, sulu

I try to setup font color with CKeditor5 in Sulu CMS (version 2.2.1), I followed [this doc](https://github.com/sulu/sulu-demo/pull/77) to do this.

So first I've added this line into assets/admin/package.json file (into "dependencies" object) :

```
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font": "^23.0.0",
```

Then I've added this lines into assets/admin/index.js file :

```
import {ckeditorPluginRegistry, ckeditorConfigRegistry} from 'sulu-admin-bundle/containers';
import Font from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/font';

ckeditorPluginRegistry.add(Font);
ckeditorConfigRegistry.add((config) => ({
    toolbar: [...config.toolbar, 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor'],
}));
```

And then I run this command : `bin/console sulu:admin:update-build`
For the questions asked, I anwser the following:

- Do you want to overwrite your local version of 'index.js' ? **N**
- Do you want to overwrite your local version of 'package.json' ? **N**
- Merge 'package.json' together like above ? **Y**
- Do you want to create a build now ? **Y**

This work great, I can set colors and background colors into my text_editor content-type.

But when I try to add an image with a single_media_selection content-type, I have an blank page with this error into the browser console :

```
TypeError: (void 0) is not a function
```

If I remove all lines that I've added, single_media_selection work great, but I can't change colors into CKeditor.

Does I made a mistake somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation you mentioned there is a [comment](https://github.com/sulu/sulu-demo/pull/77#discussion_r527754024) saying that you have to use `"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font": "^18.0.0"`, if you are using sulu 2.1 and `"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font": "^23.0.0"` if you are using sulu 2.2 and higher.

And since you mentioned, that you are using sulu 2.1, this is probably the mistake.

Comment: You've right, I forgot to mention it here : I've tried both versions.

- With `^18.0.0` I have the same problem for the single_media_selection. And for the text_editor, it like it's in read-only mode and I have this error into the browser console :  `CKEditorError: this.editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition().findAncestor is not a function`

- With `^23.0.0` it's the situation as mentionned into my question.

Comment: Set the version of `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font` back to `^18.0.0` and then run `rm -rf assets/admin/node_modules assets/admin/package-lock.json vendor/sulu/**/node_modules vendor/sulu/**/package-lock.json` in the root directory of your project and then `npm install && npm run build` inside `assets/admin/`

Comment: With this, it's the same, I can't go on another page than the admin's homepage. And I have this in the browser console : `TypeError: (void 0) is not a function`.
Btw I'm using Sulu 2.2.1 (I've fixed it into my initial question), so I use version `^23.0.0`